# Dynamically create variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a script that creates a variable called `eventData1`. In the events section, `events` are created. I want to do this job dynamically rather than have it statically in the html file.

```
    var eventData1 = {
          options: {
            timeslotsPerHour: 4,
            timeslotHeight: 20,
            defaultFreeBusy: {free: true}
          },
          events : 
            {'id':1, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 12), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30), 'title': 'Lunch with Mike', userId: 0},
            {'id':2, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45), 'title': 'Dev Meeting', userId: 1},
            {'id':3, 'start': new Date(year, month, day+1, 18), 'end': new Date(year, month, day+1, 18, 45), 'title': 'Hair cut', userId: 1},
            {'id':4, 'start': new Date(year, month, day+2, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day+2, 9, 30), 'title': 'Team breakfast', userId: 0},
            {'id':5, 'start': new Date(year, month, day+1, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day+1, 15), 'title': 'Product showcase', userId: 1}
          ]
    };
```

So my file creates another variable called `appointments`, that is set up exactly like the ones you see above:

```
[{'id': 25, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-07 14:45:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-07 15:45:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0},{'id': 26, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-10 11:15:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-10 12:15:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0}]
```

How can I replace the statically created events with my `appointments` variable?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
    var eventData1 = {
          options: {
            timeslotsPerHour: 4,
            timeslotHeight: 20,
            defaultFreeBusy: {free: true}
          },
          events : appointments
    };
```

Edit: Matt was right, the appointments variable is in scope, but not set up yet:

```
  var appointments = "[";
  var counter = 0;
   $.getJSON('link', function(data) {
        console.log('entered getJSON()');
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, appointment) {
            var id = appointment.appointmentId;
            var start = appointment.start;
            var end = appointment.end;
            var title = appointment.prename;
            var userid = appointment.workerid;

            appointments += "{'id': " + id + ", 'start': new Date( '" + start+ "'), 'end': new Date('" + end + "'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0}";

            if (i === (data.length - 1)) {
                // this is the last                    
            } else {
                appointments += ",";
            }             
            counter++;
        });

        appointments += "]";

    console.log(appointments);
    });
```

Any idea what I can do in order to have it set up before the other code is using it?

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work. Are you sure `appointments` is in scope?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what didn't work?

Comment: Did it assign to `events`, but wrongly? Or did it not assign anything to `events` and instead threw some error? Did you try printing value of `eventData1.events` after the above declaration?

Comment: @Matt, it is in scope but I just realized that it is not set up yet. I updated my question. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about where what part of the code is in your file, but I'm guessing you make the request to the server, then set `eventData1` and then handle the server response.

Javascript strings are immutable, so when you modify `appointments` `eventData1.events` isn't updated. Look at this example:

```
var str = "hi";
var obj = {myString: str}; // obj.myString = "hi"
str = "hello"; // obj.myString is still "hi"
```

The "hi" string isn't updated as it's immutable, it's overwritten by a new string.

So one thing you could do is update `eventData.events` explicitly and assign the new value of `appointments` to it.

But since `appointments` is a string representation of a Javascript array, why not use an array instead? So instead of

```
appointments += "{'id': " + id + ", 'start': new Date( '" + start+ "'), 'end': new Date('" + end + "'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0}";
```

Use

```
appointments = []; // Do this outside of the $.each
... 
appointments.push(appointments += "{'id': " + id + ", 'start': new Date( '" + start+ "'), 'end': new Date('" + end + "'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0}");
```

Comment: It says `[ has no push method`. The problem is that appointments is not completely set up when my calendar access eventData1. I don't know how I should "wait" for this to be finished.

Comment: Ok I fixed the first issue. When I use the `appointments` variable in the code (although it is now properly filled), the application crashes and says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined `. When I add it manually, it works properly. I don't know how JavaScript interprets it therefore.